# NIFI: JsonQueryElasticsearch with scrolling

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

i am on NIFI version 1.8.0 and i am trying to do query on elasticSearch.

The existing ScrollElasticsearchHttp only supports Lucene-style query but i would like to use json query. So using JsonQueryElasticsearch processor seems to be the choice. However, this processor doesn't seem to support scrolling .

Please let me know how to use Json query as well as supporting scrolling.

thank you

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to go with JSON query? The Lucene syntax is quite powerful and complete.